# How to loop through a list in a label using Tkinter?

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter, label

I am trying to create a GUI that simply prints messages after one another with some time in between.

```
list_of_tweets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


for i in list_of_tweets:
    print(i)
    time.sleep(10)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x400")

window.title("Twitterscreen")

variable=StringVar()

def update_label():
    while True:
        for i in list_of_tweets:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(10)
        variable.set(str(i))
        window.update()

label = Label(master=window,
              background='white',
              foreground='black',
              font=('Helvetica', 20),
              width=14,
              height=3)
label.config(width=200, height=300)
label.pack()

mainloop()
```

This is my code so far. When I run it, the result is just a white screen. Again, I want the label to print out the `list_of_tweets` one at a time with 10 seconds in between.

Comment: I should add, I am completely new to Tkinter so excuse any silly mistakes.

Comment: Using `time.sleep()` will make the GUI unresponsive

Comment: Is there any way to put a pause in between?

Comment: `window.after()` is a way to do so. But we cannot run this code and hence we dont know what `public_tweets` or `tweet` is

Comment: You wonder why a huge white screen is shown? Its your label background and the size youve configured it to. Just reduce the size and call the function from the main block

Comment: No need to know what 'public_tweets' is. I simply want the list of [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to loop in a screen using Tkinter.

Comment: No I expected the white screen. I want the numbers from the list to show up in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off by making your label into:

```
label = Label(master=window,
              background='white',
              foreground='black',
              font=('Helvetica', 20),
              width=200,
              height=300)
```

Now the idea I'm using here is indexing the list till it reaches the last item on the list, rather than using `for` loop. So change your function into:

```
count = 0 #index number 
def update_label():
    global count
    label.config(text=list_of_tweets[count]) #show the current indexed item
    count += 1 #increase the index number 
    rep = window.after(1000,update_label) #repeat this process every 1 second
    
    if count >= len(list_of_tweets): #if the index number greater than or equal to length of list
        window.after_cancel(rep) #stop repeating
```

So final code would be:

```
from tkinter import *

list_of_tweets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x400")

window.title("Twitterscreen")

variable = StringVar() #no use here, dont know why you would use it here

count = 0 
def update_label():
    global count

    label.config(text=list_of_tweets[count])
    count += 1
    rep = window.after(1000,update_label)
    
    if count >= len(list_of_tweets):
        window.after_cancel(rep)
    
label = Label(master=window,
              background='white',
              foreground='black',
              font=('Helvetica', 20),
              width=200,
              height=300) # no need to configure it separately when you can declare it directly

label.pack()
update_label() # call the function initially

mainloop()
```

Why doesnt it work in your example? Firstly, your setting the value of the `StringVar()` into the text, correct, but that `StringVar()` is not associated with the label at all. And using a `for` loop, you would need `time.sleep()` but that will freeze the GUI, even if you use `window.update()` the window updates, but the GUI window will be unresponsive.

**`after(ms,func)` method takes two arguments mainly:**

- `ms` - time to be run the function in millisecond(ms)
- `func` - the function to run after the given ms is finished.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for the label:

```
display_text = StringVar()
label=Label(window, textvariable=display_text)


text='Your message'
display_text.set(text)
```