# Display items of an array in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have some text in an array and I want to show this text in order and use <kbd>Next Text</kbd> and <kbd>Previous Text</kbd> `Button`s to show text, it means that I want to increase the index of the array by pressing Next and showing the text.
How can I do this in python using Tkinter?
I used a global variable to set text into it but it doesn't show in Tkinter `Label`.

```
def increase():
   global sentenceToShow
   global subtitleIndex
   subtitleIndex = subtitleIndex+1
   sentenceToShow = sentences[subtitleIndex]['sentence']
```

Comment: Do you think you could adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668425/6273251) to work using a button click rather than a timer? That basically shows you how to do it.

Comment: Post some code related to the label.

Comment: You can use `mylabel.config(text='new text')` to update an existing `Label` widget.

Comment: Change `sentenceToShow` to a tkinter `StringVar` and link this variable to the label using `textvariable` option of the label.  Then use `sentenceToShow.set(sentences[subtitleIndex]['sentence'])` inside `increase()` to update the label.